# can java classloader user different version of java to load different classes

Tags: java, dependencies, version, classloader

A module written in scala depends on A.jar (which requires java 6). When I try to start to run the module, it requires java 7 to load the main class correctly, otherwise I get classdefnotfounderror. But when I use java 7 to run the module, one function in A.jar that requires java 6 will break (saying can't load the corresponding class). How can I deal with such dilemma? Thanks.

Comment: Code, error output? can you show us these?

Comment: Error message is:  Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.hadoop.security.JniBasedUnixGroupsMapping
at org.apache.hadoop.security.JniBasedUnixGroupsMappingWithFallback.<init>(JniBasedUnixGroupsMappingWithFallback.java:38)

Comment: What is the nature of the requirement for Java 6? It's extremely unusual that something that works on Java N wouldn't also work on N+1, N+2, etc. So in order to give you good advice, we probably need to know more about this.